# Create a TypeScript Library and use it from Node.js with ES6 and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jsdoc

I want to create a TypeScript library as private npm package which can be used in Node.js (including `6.x)` using ES6 with `@types` support and TypeScript.

The goal of the library is to extend the `Request` type from `express` and provide additional properties.

I created a new Node.js project and add this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["mocha"]
  }
}
```

These are the relevant parts of the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/my-lib",
  "main": "dist",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "joi": "11.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies":  {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

My folder structure is this:

```
- dist
- src
  - http
  - security
- test
```

I created a new TypeScript file `AuthenticatedRequest.ts` in `src/http`:

```
import {Request} from "express";
import {UserReference} from "../security/UserReference";

export interface AuthenticatedRequest extends Request {
  user: UserReference
}
```

`src/security` contains a `UserReference.ts`:

```
import {Claim} from "./Claim";

export interface UserReference {
  claims: Claim[];
}
```

and a `Claim.ts`:

```
import {IClaim} from "./IClaim";

export class Claim implements IClaim {
  type: string;
  value: string;

  constructor(type: string, value: string) {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

`IClaim.ts` looks like this:

```
export interface IClaim {
  type: string,
  value: string
}
```

In `test`, I created `AuthenticatedRequestTests.js` (plain ES6, no TypeScript here to validation code completion and usage from ES6):

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');
const Claim = require("../dist/security/Claim").Claim;

describe('req', () => {
  it('should ', done => {
    /** @type {AuthenticatedRequest} */
    const req = {};
    req.user = { claims: [new Claim('tenantId', '123')] };
    assert.equal(req.user.claims[ 0 ].type, 'tenantId');
    assert.equal(req.user.claims[ 0 ].value, '123');
    return done();
  });
});
```

Now I have sevaral questions:

- Is this the expected TypeScript way to solve this?
- Is it possible to just use `require("../dist/security/Claim");` instead of `require("../dist/security/Claim").Claim;`?
- Instead of using this `jsdoc` statement `/** @type {AuthenticatedRequest} */` I would like to use `/** @type {myLib.http.AuthenticatedRequest} */`

I also created a local test project for integration and installed my library via `npm link`.

But instead of using

`const Claim = require("@scope/my-lib/security/Claim").Claim;` I have to use

`const Claim = require("@scope/my-lib/dist/security/Claim").Claim;`

How can I get rid of the `dist` folder name here?

Also, using the `jsdoc` comment for `AuthenticatedRequest` in the integration test project, I get the error that the type cannot be found:

[image]

Comment: You can create `src/index.ts` and export everything from that file (e.g. `export * from './security/Claim'`). Then from your JS code just require `@scope/my-lib`. As for `const Claim = require(...).Claim`, use destructuring: `const {Claim} = require(...)`. You can `console.log(require(...))` if you are unsure what is exported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`package.json`**

- There should be a field called `types` (or `typings`) telling your library consumers where are the type definitions for your project. If they are generated by TypeScript and saved to `dist/index.d.ts`, then that's the path that should be used.

  `"types": "./dist/index.d.ts"`
- There should be a field called `files` containing an array of files/directories that will be delivered to your end users.

**Running tests**

- > Is this the expected TypeScript way to solve this?

  If you're using TypeScript to develop your library, there is no reason not to use TypeScript for your tests. There are TypeScript-compliant test runners out there (`ts-jest` used to be popular, and now Jest is capable of understanding TypeScript out of the box).
- > Is it possible to just use `require("../dist/security/Claim");` instead of `require("../dist/security/Claim").Claim;`?

  With TypeScript, a few kinds of syntax are possible. You could export `Claim` using a default export and do:

  ```
  import Claim from "../dist/security/Claim";
  ```

  or:

  ```
  const Claim = require("../dist/security/Claim");
  ```
- > Instead of using this jsdoc statement `/** @type {AuthenticatedRequest} */` I would like to use `/** @type {myLib.http.AuthenticatedRequest} */`.

  You will need an *import type*. They look like that:

  ```
  /**
   * @type {import('path/to/AuthenticatedRequest')}
   */
  const req {}
  ```

  The path can be relative or absolute. If you'd like to treat the local codebase as if it were installed from npm, you can create another `package.json` file in your test directory and use a relative path to resolve your library module.

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    "my-library": "../path/to/the/root"
  }
  ```
- > Also, using the jsdoc comment for `AuthenticatedRequest` in the integration test project, I get the error that the type cannot be found:

  That's also solved by import types. Unless a type is not in the global scope, you need to import it before you can use it. Use `import('path/to/AuthenticatedRequest')` instead.

---

There are a few things going on. If you could create a public repository to demonstrate your problems, I'm sure it would be easier for us to help you address them.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations so far. I created two repositories: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/repro-54357435-usage (the second is linked in the first). Usage details can be found in `readme.md`

Comment: Done, see the pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate answer for one part of your question.  You asked

> instead of using
>
> `const Claim = require("@scope/my-lib/security/Claim").Claim;` I have to use
>
> `const Claim = require("@scope/my-lib/dist/security/Claim").Claim;`
>
> How can I get rid of the dist folder name here?

As Karol points out, you can use `files` in `package.json` so that when your library is published, you send the `dist` directory as the package root ([plus `package.json`, README, etc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)).  This is a great, established pattern, but has some downsides: installing the package from `github:` instead of NPM won't work, nor will `npm link` for local development.

As of very recent Node versions, you can use [the `exports` property](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_exports) instead:

```
{
  "exports": {
    "./": "./dist/"
  }
}
```

Now, `require("my_lib/security/Claim")` resolves to `node_modules/my_lib/dist/security/Claim`.  It would be great if Typescript handled this automatically, but as far as I can tell you also have to specify a `baseUrl` and `paths` in your `tsconfig.json`, at least for now.

Comment: Thanks, thats an interesting addition.