# TypeScript module structure in JS with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to publish a TypeScript library using webpack and with a folder structure like:

```
src/
    module1/
        some-class.ts
        index.ts
    module2/
        some-other-class.ts
        index.ts
    etc/
```

If used in TS, I should be able to do:

```
import { SomeClass } from 'my-library/module1';
```

And when using require, should be able to do:

```
const SomeClass = require('my-library/module1');
```

Webpack needs an entry (or multiple entries) and outs files matching those entries. However, I see defining entries for every nested folder very impractical, and also don't know how to make deep nested entries like `require('my-library/module1/submodule1/etc')`.

Also, authored that way, it might not follow the dts files outputted by the `ts-loader`.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to make webpack replicate the module structure of the TS sources?

Am I using the wrong tool?

If so, what do people use to bundle libraries?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357435/create-a-typescript-library-and-use-it-from-node-js-with-es6-and-typescript/

Comment: would be great if you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just create an index.ts file in your toplevel src/ directory and export every subfolder from there, for example `export * from 'module1';`

And when you create a new module you simply need to add the a new line to export the proper directory.

On a side note, if you want to export something from your top level that is actually deeper inside a module you can use the following syntax `export { myFunc } from './module1/nested/myFunc';`

In that case your use can `require('myLibrary/myFunc')` instead of `require('myLibrary/module1/nested/myFunc')`

Edit: As pointed out by @Dehli those index files are called Barrels (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html)